# Potential leak of object

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

Can any help me understand why I am getting a this issue when running analyze?

I am having a potential leak of an object stored into "oldShadowPath".

```
-(void) layoutShadowWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    CGPathRef oldShadowPath = self.mainViewController.view.layer.shadowPath;

    if (oldShadowPath)
    {
        CFRetain(oldShadowPath);
    }

    // Update shadow path for the view
    CGPathRef path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.mainViewController.view.bounds].CGPath;
    self.mainViewController.view.layer.shadowPath = path;

    // You would think setting duration to 0 would cause the animation added below to not animate. You would be wrong.
    if (duration != 0) {
        if (oldShadowPath)
        {
            [self.mainViewController.view.layer addAnimation:((^ {
                CABasicAnimation *transition = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"shadowPath"];
                transition.fromValue = (__bridge id)oldShadowPath;
                transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
                transition.duration = duration;
                return transition;
            })()) forKey:@"transition"];

            CFRelease(oldShadowPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If `duration` is 0, then `oldShadowPath` is never released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you don't have CFRelease corresponding to each CFRetain. You release object in double 'if' statement, where one of them is independent from retain condition ("oldShadowPath").

Comment: Thanks for that. The problem is that I've tried adding an else statement to take care of the duration == 0. with `else { CFRelease(oldShadowPath);}` but then I had null pointer call to CFrelease.

Comment: Yes, you should also check 'oldShadowPath' for nil. Why not just release it outside those ifs and check only if(oldShadowPath)? Edit: or maybe better: you probably could separate logic for oldShadowPath case. And if you don't need to do anything when it's nil, you can just check it in first line, and return in case of nil.

Answer (score -1):

As @H2CO3 commented, if `duration` is 0, then `oldShadowPath` is never released.